# Travel to Cuba with a B2 Visa

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, cuba

This is just a hypothetical. If I were to apply for a B2 USA visa and then go to Cuba, will I be permitted entry into the USA?

As I understand it the US still doesn't allow tourism for its citizens, do they also place restrictions on existing visa-holders?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a B2 Tourist Visa for the USA you can travel to Cuba. You will need to get a Pink Tourist Card and fill the Affidavit form. The information provided on this link will apply to all travellers from the EU and that are part of the Visa Waver Program for visiting the USA. https://www.cubavisa.uk/travelling-usa-cuba-info-uk-travellers/